# PluginLifecycle - start/stop not called in managed plugin

Tags: neo4j

I have a pretty basic managed plugin and I have custom implementation of [PluginLifeCycle](http://components.neo4j.org/server-api/milestone/apidocs/org/neo4j/server/plugins/PluginLifecycle.html), and include the fully qualified class name in the file, META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginLifecycle, but for some reason the start and stop of my custom implementation are not getting called.
This is a managed plugin, and my extension (which implements the ServerPlugin)  works.

Did someone else have any luck with a custom implementation of  PluginLifeCycle in a managed extension/plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the codebase, but couldn't find a test usage for the https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/server/src/test/java/org/dummy/web/service/DummyPluginInitializer.java class.

Writing a test for that and raising an issue it the right approach, if you can recreate this behavior.